# How to monitor geoserver map performance using jmeter?

Tags: geoserver, apache

I want to monitor the geoserver map performance using jmeter which is been load balanced in Apache http server, now I want to know how should I achieve this and what all changes I have to do in jmeter.

Can anyone tell us the steps for configuring jmeter and how i can see the performance while using geoserver as well as by calling in openlayers.

These are the results when I call an application and how do I evaluate performance by this results.

[image: aggregate report]
[image: Graph Result]
[image: view result in tree]